# Cleaning repository for a certain file type

Tags: fossil

By mistake I forgot to add `*.pyc` to `ignore-glob`, and now they litter my repository. Is there a way to remove them from my repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've added *.pyc to your ignore-glob, do a `fossil rm *.pyc`, then commit the change.